# How to get notified on model changes in generic way with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using `Ember` and `Ember Data` and I would like to listen to any changes relevant for a specific model.

For example in my app I could have an Order model with two fields - `attr1` and `attr2`.

The two use cases/questions are:

1. How to get notified when new `Order` instances get added or deleted to/from store. Something like store.on(modelName, 'deleted/added', listener). modelName in this case would equal 'order'.
2. How to get notified on any change within all models of specific type in the store. Something like store.on(modelName, 'modelUpdated', listener). I don't want to specify in which attributes I am interested because I am interested in any change in any attribute.

Any ideas and pointers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ember-data provides lifecycle callbacks for DS.Model objects. Have a look to the events panel of the [doc](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the store to achieve the behavior in point 1. We will use an event name of "added:*modelName*".

```
this.store.reopen(Ember.Evented, {
    createRecord(model) { 
        this.trigger('added' + ':' + model);
        return this._super(...arguments);
    }
}
```

Point 2 is harder.

To listen from somewhere:

```
listen: function() { this.store.on('added:order'), this.handleAddedOrder; }
```